# Routes not working without index.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Im using laravel 4.

I have a view `nest.blade.php` and the corresponding controller `NestController.php:`

Controller content:

```
class NestController extends BaseController {

    public function showView()
    {
        return View::make('nest');
    }

}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/nest', 'NestController@showView');
```

When I go to url/nest it doesnt work. 
When I go to url/index.php/nest it does work.

Obviously I just want it to be /nest without the index.php.

How can i resolve this?

My htaccess:

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Based on your .htaccess it seems you are running Laravel 4.1? Anyhow, I copied your route and controller into my environments (both 4.0 and 4.1) and everything works smoothyl with `/nest` url. Nothing wrong in those.

Comment: interesting. Could it be anything to do with my vhosts? Or did i not do something during install that enables routes to work? all these possibilities im pondering. Yes, the latest version i am running.

Comment: Yes, I would look into those, but unfortunately that's outside my knowledge. As I said, everything works perfectly in my env with your routes.php, controller and even .htaccess. My apache2 is running with all default settings, so nothing special is required there either.

Comment: I suggest you add a rewrite rule to prevent access to your .env file and other files in your root folder when to you use this method. Try accessing your .env file from your projects root like **http://your-project/.env** 
I suggest a rewrite rule like below:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)env$ 404.php`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Pretty URLs

> The framework ships with a public/.htaccess file that is used to allow
>   URLs without index.php. If you use Apache to serve your Laravel
>   application, be sure to **enable the mod_rewrite module**.

If the `.htaccess` file that ships with Laravel does not work with your
 Apache installation, try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

For more related help, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2).

Comment: I will aceept your answer thanks. For anyone else, do not use the code above, the answer was in the link, I had to a2enmod rewrite

Comment: @TheAlpha dude this took me around 4 hours now. It finally works! thanks!!

Comment: @JoshHarington, Glad you made it finally :-)

Comment: The first one works for me. I would try your answer if only it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I enabled the mod_rewrite module in the Apache HTTP server, restarted Apache service and tested again and it WORKED!!!

Below is the code i used to enable mode_rewrite;

1) Un-Hash this line in Apache/conf/httpd.conf

> LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

2) Create a new configuration for "sample-project" without modifying the default configuration in the httpd.conf file

```
Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/sample-project">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
Directory>
```

Comment: i used for ubuntu server

cd /etc/apache2;
sudo su;
vim apache2.conf;

and i added 

<Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

Answer (score 4):

Be Alert! If it is not working even after enabling rewrite module. You need to change the line "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" in httpd.conf.

As @The Alpha alerted, Laravel don't need to be configured for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

First of All you need to set `AllowOverride All` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Find the following block:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**↓↓↓↓ THIS IS AN IMPORTANT PART THAT MANY PEOPLE MISS ↓↓↓↓**

**DO NOT** forget to run a2enmode

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and then

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This way you apply it for all your laravel projects (inside `/var/www/` folder).

Comment: After trying multiple solutions, this is the one which actually worked. Thanks.

Comment: This answer should get more attention -- `a2enmod rewrite` was the key for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When you change the line `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in `httpd.conf` be sure that you do it inside `<directory ...>` that contains valid path.

Example

```
<Directory "/var/www/html"> #check path
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: You are right, only apply the statement "AllowOverride All" in our specific web content directory such as in your code above, not in the  <Directory /></Directory> section/block. It's mentioned clearly in the httpd.conf remark.

Answer (score 2):

**For some reasons the answers above are not working for me, so here is the only one that worked for me.**

**I am using** `ubuntu 18.04 amd64` **as my development server environment.
So I modified** `apache.conf` **file located at**`/etc/apache2`

> > **From:**

```
<Directory /var/www/> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride None Require all granted
```

> > **To:**

```
<Directory /var/www/> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride All Require all granted
```

> > **And Also From:**

```
<Directory /usr/share> AllowOverride None Require all granted
```

> > **To**

```
<Directory /usr/share> AllowOverride All Require all granted
```

After that, you need to restart `apache` using `sudo service apapche2 restart` command in the terminal

Now I can access the page without using index.php in the URL

Credit goes to: **joshymatheww** @ [Laracasts servers discussion channel on 
Aug 5, 2017](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/urls-only-work-when-indexphp-is-used)

Answer (score 2):

Login to the terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

After line

```
<Directory /var/www/>
.
.
.
</Directory>
```

and paste below code

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Now Ctrl+O and then Ctrl+M and then Ctrl+x

Now restart apache server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following .htaccess. I never had any trouble with that on a server or localhost environment.

DirectoryIndex index.php

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
        RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
        RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule .? - [L]

        RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]

    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

set this in your .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```